# Passbook push notification on Android?

Tags: passbook

Is there a way to send push notification with passbook on android ?

I found this https://www.pass2u.net, but i'm not quite convinced...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass2u have an open API and offer free access to pass issuers with less than 1000 updates per month.  One advantage over PassWallet is that their revenue model is not dependent upon advertising.

Both pass2u and PassWallet have reliable APIs that closely mirror the Passbook webservice and can be easily implemented with minimal overhead.

One further advantage of Pass2u over PassWallet is their support for Baidu push.  If you have users in China then PassWallet updates will not work because they are dependent on the Google cloud messaging APIs which are not available.

Answer (score 0):

The PassWallet app supports push notifications. It uses the same mechanism and API as Passbook/Wallet on iOS, the only difference being where you send the push notifications.

When a pass is installed, it registered with your service as normal, but in addition to the serial number etc. a URL is provided too. You then send a message to that URL.

You'll find more info here http://attidomobile.com/portfolio/passwallet/

Comment: Hi, I don't see any developper documentation ? where I can found it ?

Comment: This is the most recent one I could find. http://passwallet.attidomobile.com/PassWallet%20Developer%20Guide.pdf

Comment: https://github.com/Kwiket/passwallet - new documentation